# Ajax event on dynamic search

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, search

1) I have a dynamic search engine (ajax) that give me a list of results (this part works fine)
2) I want to settle an event "hover() on the results of the search (they get the .

The results of the search get the class "city_found", that I use as a selector. 
I have written a static

paragraph to test the event. It works fine.

The Ajax code:

```
$(function(){

    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        if ( $('#search').val().length > 1)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: "/etudevet/search/", //path to the url in url.py
                data:{
                    'search_text' : $('#search').val(),
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
                },
                success: searchSuccess,
                dataType: "html"
            });
            }
    });

$(".city_fond").hover(function(){
    alert( "click" );
});


});


function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    $('#search-results').html(data);
}
```

The html (django template):

```
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" id="search" name="city" >

<p class="city_found">hoverme</p>     <!--used to test the hover-->


<ul id ="search-results"></ul>
```

When I am trying to hover the results, nothing happens (the class is right).
I think this has something to do with the fact that the page is already loaded but since I'm a beginner in Ajax, I couldn't figure it out.
Any Idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time you attach the hover event handler, you do not have any elements with the "city_found" class. There are two ways to fix this:

(1) You can delay setting the event handler until after the elements are added:

```
function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $('#search-results').html(data).find(".city_found").hover(function(){
        alert( "click" );
    });
}
```

(2) You could use event delegation:

```
$(document).on("hover", ".city_found", function() {
    alert( "click" );
});
```

Comment: First one works well. Where should I put the event delegation?

Comment: Shouldn't it be from the "search-results" div that I should set the delegation?

Comment: @sana - With event delegation you are attaching a "hover" handler on the document, but it will only call the function when the target element has the "city_found" class. You would put that code right where you originally had `$(".city_fond").hover(function(){ alert( "click" ); });`. But you don't need to do both (1) & (2), just one of them.